# Cannot build Google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

Following the tutorial for Google maps integration in Android, I installed Google play services from the SDK Manager and then imported the google-play-services_lib folder in my workspace. The problem is that I get 20 errors in

1. res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
2. res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
3. res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
4. res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_light.xml

on every item declared inside those 4 files. Example(first error)

```
No resource found that matches the given name(at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark')
```

How do I solve those errors?

Comment: did you add the library to your project?

Comment: Yup, but there's a big bold red X in front of the reference name. The errors come from the library itself, not my project

Comment: i think the address of the library is not where it reference just remove that library and add it again from proper location.

Comment: None helped. Instead I deleted the \res\drawable folder, now it doesn't have any problems

Comment: I too have the same issue....u deleted your projects drawable folder???